# Open database with brutalist architecture?

Tags: architecture

My apologies if I’m in the wrong SE.

Is there an open database of brutalist buildings? I’m aware of sosBrutalism; adding to their data is gatekept and not openly, programmatically, available. So, I’m looking for something that’s open in the sense that Wikipedia is open.

(By accident, I stumbled upon sosBrutalism's full dataset of images, including the buildings they reference, [here](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/brutalism-photos@public/table/?rows=5000&location=3,7.36247,10.19531&basemap=mapbox.streets). Still gatekept, but also open.)

Comment: The existence of the [BRUTALISM:ONLINE](http://brutalism.online/) project to document all Brutalist buildings world-wide suggests that nobody already has a list of them.

Comment: Thanks @JohnDallman. I wasn’t aware of that resource. Something like that would be perfect, if it had an API.

Comment: If you can read their data, you can make your own API.

Comment: @AaronBrick: Yeah. I don't think I can write to that datasource, but reading is a good start.

Answer (score 4):

Although far from exhaustive, I suggest using Wikidata. There are [168 items](http://tinyurl.com/ycrkm7ut) with "architectural style" property set to "brutalism".

In addition, the [list of brutalist structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_brutalist_structures) in Wikipedia seems more complete than Wikidata. The [equivalent list in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Bauwerken_des_Brutalismus) may be worth checking because it could contain more structures than the English one - or at least some different ones.

In fact, if you plan to collaborate to expand a database about brutalist architecture, Wikidata and Wikipedia are great places.

Comment: Thanks. That's a really nice and generalised solution. I played around a bit and it's not hard to extract data in JSON format. But... the list of buildings is rather limited. And the process for adding and editing content is even more Spartan than it is for Wikipedia, meaning the average user will easily be put off from contributing.